# Remote Upload File With Uploaded Size

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, progress, filesize

For Example, I've created a file (upload.php) with the following content and uploaded it to my server:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$put = file_put_content('./' . basename($url),file_get_contents($url));

if($put){
      echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
}
```

Well, now on other server, I have this form:

```
<input type="url" id="url">

<a onclick="doUpload()">Upload</a>


<div id="uploaded_size"></div>

<script>
         function doUpload() {
                  $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'http://example.com/upload.php',
                    data: {
                      url: $('#url').val()
                    },
                    beforeSend: function (data){
                      //i want show uploaded file size in this area or in success function.
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    },
                  })
      }
<script>
```

How can I view the uploaded file size every 2 seconds using this method?
eg:

```
          function SetProgressStart() {
            doProgress = setInterval(
              showProgress, 2000);
          }

          function showProgress() {
              $('#uploaded_size').html();
          }
```

---

**UPDATE**:

i've make this trick, Look :

```
  $url = $_GET['url'];
  $name = basename($url);

 //Here we request the file size:
  if(isset($_GET['size']))
  {
       // Get Uploading File Size
      $filesize = filesize($name);
      die(json_encode(array('uploaded' => $filesize)));
  }

   $put = @file_put_content('./' . $name, @file_get_contents($url));

   if($put){
         echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
   }
```

But the problem is that the file is being uploaded, until the operation is completed, is not in the folder. So I need a method that can not handle the file while uploading in the Temporary Folder.
anyway, if this method is work, for every 2 seconds request to url, there is a possibility of blocking the browser from the server.So this is not a good way :(

Comment: it complex task, create background process on server, do Ajax in `showProgress()` to check current downloaded file size.

Comment: thanks ewwink, But I want to know exactly this.I've seen a lot of places doing it.